# Nullable With Surprising Result

Tags: c#

What prints this program?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? other = null;
    int value = 100 + other ?? 0;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

I know I just do not have the language specs in my head. But still it is surprising that it prints 0 instead of 100. Is there a reasonable explanation for this strange behavior?

When I use braces then I get the right result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? other = null;
    int value = 100 + (other ?? 0);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: It's called "operator precedence", and you've discovered that the `+` operator is evaluated before the null coalesce `??`

Comment: Why are you surprised? Your question implies you understand operator precedence but you state you  are unsure which operator will be evaluated first. Other than "unary addition has higher precedence than null coalescence" what answer are you expecting, this seems tautological. Any additional speculation on the reasoning behind this is subjective and if low value, unless perhaps we have direct input from one of the designers of the C# language.

Comment: At the time I did write the code it looked ok but the behavior did prove me wrong. I would like to know why it was designed this way. What would break if + has higher precedence than ?? ?

Comment: @AloisKraus, well all the code that assumes the current precedence would break. Speculation on why is off-topic and overly broad, I'd recommend CS or Maths Exchange if you really want to know.

Comment: @Jodrell, its not unary addition, its the additive operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence of C# operators is defined [clearly here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6a71f45d(v=vs.140).aspx).

We can see,

> x + y – addition.

is 29th, and,

> x ?? y – returns x if it is non-null; otherwise, returns y.

is 46th, so Additive Addition is evaluated before Null Coalescence.

Speculation of the reasoning behind this is off-topic for this site and a much deeper question. Answers here will likely be [subjective, even with direct input from the technical group](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/04/21/precedence-ordering-or-grouping/), and a complete answer will be longer than a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 5):

Currently the expression evaluates as:

```
(100 + other) ?? 0;
```

The value of `other` is null and a number plus null is still null. So the expression outputs 0.

In your second example, you are evaluating the null check first, then adding 100.

Comment: If I may ask there what does the ?? do in this case ?  (I only know the single ? so far for an if. is ?? there because of the nullable?)

Comment: ?? is the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and it returns the left side, unless it is null in which case it returns the right side.

Comment: @Thomas The null coalesce operator says: "Assign the left side unless the left hand side is null, then assign the right hand side".

Comment: @Thomas `a ?? b` means `a != null ? a : b`, i.e. `a` if `a` is not `null`, otherwise `b`.

Comment: ah tnx so in essence it is an extended shortcut (with ? being the base shortcut and ?? including the == null and the else path). interesting. Tnx!

Comment: @Thomas, exactly, it's an example of [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)

Answer (score 5):

You are getting the result as 0 because of `plus(+)` operator having [**higher precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) over  `Null Coalescing Operator` `??`. So your expression is evaluated as:

```
(100 + other) ?? 0;
```

which returns 0.

In your second case you are evaluating the expression (other ?? 0) first giving it the higher precedence. And hence you get the correct or the expected result.